# How to resolve this error while starting development server using npm on VS code environment

Tags: vue.js, npm

I'm starting development server on VS code for my Vue.js project.

When I start my server by using `npm run serve` script, I got this error message in the terminal below.

Can anyone help me please?

```
> vue-cli-service serve --mode=development

 INFO  Starting development server...
98% after emitting CopyPlugin

 ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 error                                                                                                                                                    오전 10:02:02

 error  in ./node_modules/headers-polyfill/lib/index.mjs

Module parse failed: Unexpected token (296:53)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders
|     // and the normalized header name to ease the lookup.
|     this[_b] = /* @__PURE__ */ new Map();
>     if (["Headers", "HeadersPolyfill"].includes(init?.constructor.name) || init instanceof _Headers) {
|       const initialHeaders = init;
|       initialHeaders.forEach((value, name) => {

 @ ./node_modules/msw/lib/esm/index.js 255:0-51 262:22-37 421:0-43 424:22-29 632:0-55 636:0-55 640:0-55 665:19-27 787:17-25 844:0-51 847:18-33 957:17-25 1160:0-71 1162:26-42
 @ ./src/mocks/browser.js
 @ ./src/main.js
 @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080&sockPath=/sockjs-node (webpack)/hot/dev-server.js ./src/main.js
```

This is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "uidev-project-template",
  "version": "2.3.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "serve": "vue-cli-service serve --mode=development",
    "build": "vue-cli-service build",
    "ide": "npm run ide_desc & vue-cli-service build --mode=ide --dest=uidev/ide/dist",
    "ide_desc": "node ./uidev/ide/build/descriptorBuild.js",
    "ide_icon": "node ./uidev/ide/build/customIconBuild.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.17.9",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-modules-commonjs": "^7.10.1",
    "@vue/babel-preset-app": "^4.4.5",
    "axios": "^0.21.1",
    "babel-helper-hoist-variables": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-cjs-system-wrapper": "^0.6.2",
    "buffer": "^6.0.3",
    "core-js": "^3.22.7",
    "exceljs": "^4.3.0",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "image-to-base64": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "moment": "^2.22.0",
    "msw": "^0.41.0",
    "puppeteer": "^13.7.0",
    "string-strip-html": "^8.3.0",
    "uidev-component": "file:local_modules/uidev-component-2.3.0.tgz",
    "url-polyfill": "^1.1.12",
    "vue": "~2.6.14",
    "vue-cookies": "^1.7.0",
    "vue-i18n": "^8.26.8",
    "vue-notification": "^1.3.20",
    "vue-router": "^3.5.2",
    "vuex": "^3.6.2",
    "xml-parser": "^1.2.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/generator": "^7.9.5",
    "@babel/parser": "^7.9.4",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/polyfill": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.1",
    "@babel/traverse": "^7.9.5",
    "@vue/babel-plugin-transform-vue-jsx": "^1.1.2",
    "@vue/cli-plugin-babel": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/cli-service": "^4.5.0",
    "@vue/eslint-config-prettier": "^6.0.0",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.1.0",
    "eslint": "^6.7.2",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.1.3",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^6.2.2",
    "js-module-formats": "^0.1.2",
    "prettier": "^1.19.1",
    "sass": "^1.49.0",
    "sass-loader": "^10.0.3",
    "stylelint": "^13.12.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^21.0.0",
    "stylelint-order": "^4.1.0",
    "stylelint-scss": "^3.19.0",
    "vue-template-compiler": "~2.6.14"
  },
  "msw": {
    "workerDirectory": "public"
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm going to guess your Node.js version is too old. What version are you running?

Comment: My node version is "18.17.1" pretty latest version.

Comment: could you check your webpack config or vue.config.js.

are you specify loader for .mjs file?

Comment: Node could also be too new... Not all packages support the latest Node version. When I try `yarn install` with the given package.json (removing the local-only uidev-component package) I get `error @achrinza/node-ipc@9.2.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "8 || 10 || 12 || 14 || 16 || 17". Got "18.13.0"`